# When modifying Dispose(bool) in a winforms generated .Designer.cs file is it necessary to move Dispose to the main code file?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have found mixed opinions regarding this question in answers to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014242/implement-disposebool-on-a-usercontrol) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052147/how-do-i-extend-a-winforms-dispose-method), but have not found a question that directly addresses it.

Is it necessary to move the Dispose method, in a winforms generated .Designer.cs file, to the main code file so that the designer will not overwrite changes I have made to the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you won't lose it.  But move it, the customization isn't discoverable in a file that nobody ever looks at.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I should have double checked before posting

Comment: I certainly agree with the discoverable aspect of it, I just wondered if moving it was strictly necessary. The evidence further digging has turned up supporting the conclusion that moving it is not necessary is that the Dispose() method appears to be coming from the Windows Forms template file located in \Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Forms\1033\Form.zip and that the Dispose method is not contained in the Windows Form Designer generated code region of the .Designer.cs file.